# Sample Flow Charts

Tags: flowchart

I need to create a flowchart to show Developer computers, Development server, Development DB,
QA Server, QA DB, Staging Server, Staging DB, Production Server and Production DB as part of creating a process so that developers follow the same during the development to staging to production development cycle.

Could you please direct me to the right URL or resource.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/) in the past for my flowcharts and it meets the basic needs.

Most of the standard components - servers etc are all there and you can usually find and download free stencils from the net for more specific needs

A process flow like you are talking about should be easily manageable using the standard stecils itself.

There seem to be a lot of online sites that provide this kind of service free lately.
You can check out this [link](http://www.visual-blast.com/online-tools/7-free-online-tools-for-creating-flow-charts-diagrams-floor-plans-and-more/). I have not used any of these before so cannot vouch for them though i did try out [flowchart.com](http://flowchart.com/) and it seemed pretty ok

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for inspiration, figure A in this post looks similar to what you're trying to do, albeit simplified slightly: http://blog.sysbliss.com/uncategorized/release-management-with-atlassian-bamboo-and-jira.html

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a tool to make **network diagrams**.

These are some candidates I found looking for *Network Diagram* at Google:

- [SmartDraw](http://www.smartdraw.com/specials/ppc/network.htm?id=128248&gclid=CMe9nZfLnKQCFYbD7QodljazEQ), A friend recommended it to me some time ago
- [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/network-diagram-software/) looks promising

Answer (score -1):

To make a flowchart from source code is so complicated, but I found an code to flowchart converter software, it can create flowchart from source code automatically, I got this software from http://flowchart-creator.com. It is free to download and free to try.

Comment: The question is not about creating flowchart from source code.